# Fast transform from string to dict in python

Tags: python

I want to transform string like "a=b,c=d,e=f..etc"
But i don't know if there is a better way to transform from string to list
It looks ugly but it works.

```
string_a="a=b,b=c"    
list_a=[[x.split('=')[0],x.split('=')[1]]  for  x in string_a.split(',')]       
dict_a=dict(list_a)
print(dict_a)
```

Answer (score 3):

Dicts can be instantiated from key, value pairs:

```
dict_a=dict(x.split('=', 1)  for  x in string_a.split(','))
```